# Transaction in SSIS Package is hanging

Tags: sql-server, session, ssis, transactions

I have an SSIS package (built w/Visual Studio 2012) with various Execute SQL Tasks in it. It's running as a job on SQL Server 2012. In the package properties I have TransactionOption set to Required; all of the tasks' TransactionOption settings are Supported. IsolationLevel is set to Serializable on everything. Suddenly yesterday, one of the tasks started hanging. If I run this task individually, it runs fine. If I disable it and run the rest of the package, there's no problem. However if this task is enabled and I try to run the package, it hangs at this task, and blocks all sessions behind it. The only way I can get the entire package to run properly is to change the package's TransactionOption setting to Supported (i.e., turn transactions off). Here's what the offending task does:

```
update timekeep
set tkemail = u.EMail,
tkmoddate = getdate(),
tkmoduser = 'appmgr' 
from ALLUSERDATA.AllUserData.dbo.[User] u 
where u.Login COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI = tkinit 
and tkemail <> u.EMail COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

I've tried putting WITH (ROWLOCK) after the UPDATE statement, but that doesn't help. The timekeep table is used by multiple people throughout the company all day, but the SSIS package is scheduled to run at 3:45 am, and it's still hanging. Again, this just started yesterday morning. The DBA says nothing on the server has changed. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: sounds like it is involved with blocking from another process. what other processes are impacting the tables?  Do you get any error statements at all?

Comment: A comment and then a few questions:  Check the settings for the database logs.  If your package does a lot of updates you may be auto-growing the transaction log a lot, which can cause performance issues.  When you say "hangs at this task", what exactly do you mean?  How long have you given it to resume working?
Also, does the entire package truly need to be done in a single transaction?

Comment: @Matt - I get no error messages from my package. The table is a main table in our Accounting system, so there are tons of processes that touch the table constantly during the day. But in the middle of the night, it should be fine (and has been for years).

Comment: @Brian - I'll ask the DBA to check the database logs. When I say "hangs at this task", I mean that the process shows as blocked on the database server. It's been left for hours and does not resolve.

Comment: what's running on the SPID that is blocking the SSIS package?